# Webpack sass-loader: How to correctly use fonts?

Tags: css, fonts, webpack, vue.js, sass-loader

So I have the following font setup:

```
$font-path: '~@/assets/fonts/';
@font-face {
    font-family: 'mainFont';
    font-weight: 300;
    font-style: normal;
    src: url('#{$font-path}mainFont/mainFont.eot') format('eot'),
    url('#{$font-path}mainFont/mainFont.woff2') format('woff2'),
    url('#{$font-path}mainFont/mainFont.woff') format('woff'),
    url('#{$font-path}mainFont/mainFont.ttf') format('truetype'),
    url('#{$font-path}mainFont/mainFont.svg#mainFont') format('svg');
}
```

The build (with vue.js webpack btw) works as expected. The app won't be able to load the fonts though. the `src` urls point to the wrong directory.
When changing the `$font-path` to the folder relative to the output file ([as suggested](https://github.com/webpack-contrib/sass-loader#problems-with-url)), the build fails because it can't find the fonts.

Comment: I don't know if it will work, but take a look at [resolve-url-loader](https://github.com/bholloway/resolve-url-loader)

Answer (score 15):

Use [file-loader](https://github.com/webpack-contrib/file-loader) and in your rules use something like this (example taken from my project):

```
{
    test: /\.(woff2?|ttf|otf|eot|svg)$/,
    exclude: /node_modules/,
    loader: 'file-loader',
    options: {
        name: '[path][name].[ext]'
    }
}
```

This will copy the files into your build folder and will inject the correct URLs to those files in your CSS.

Second thing is to add [resolve-url-loader](https://github.com/bholloway/resolve-url-loader) to your scss rule:

```
{
    test: /\.scss$/,
    use: ExtractTextPlugin.extract({
        fallback: 'style-loader',
        use: ['css-loader', 'resolve-url-loader', 'sass-loader?sourceMap']
    })
}
```

Comment: file-loader is now deprecated